# What is the difference between copyright infringment, and intellectual property violation?

Tags: copyright

What is the difference between copyright infringment and intellectual property violation?

Comment: What's the difference between a banana and a fruit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copyright infringement is just one of several ways to violate a person's intellectual property rights. Others include patent infringement, trademark infringement, and misappropriation of trade secrets.